# check if null value inside Json response flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
user = User(
    membership:json.decode(response.body["MembershipStatus"],
    userCode:  json.decode(response.body) ["ResultObject"]["UserCode"],
    username:  json.decode(response.body) ["ResultObject"]["UserName"] ?? "",
    startDate:json.decode(response.body) ["ResultObject"]["MemberShipDetails"]["StartDate"]?? "",
    endDate: json.decode(response.body)  ["ResultObject"]["MemberShipDetails"]["EndDate"]?? "",
);
```

How to check for null value when initialize constructor in flutter,

If value of "MemberShipDetails" is null the app will crash,
How to check the value of "MemberShipDetails" before getting "StartDate" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` like this to return `null` if the previous result was `null`:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  dynamic value =
      jsonDecode('{"MemberShipDetails": null}')?["MemberShipDetails"]
              ?["EndDate"] ??
          'Hey, we got a null!';
  print(value); // Hey, we got a null!
}
```

Comment: I got this message This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.

Comment: @Ahmed I assume Dart 2.12 or newer (and therefore the non-null by default feature) is used unless other is specified. The feature I use was introduced with 2.12. What version of Dart are you specifying to be compatible with in your pubspec.yaml file? Can you update to 2.12 (or newer)?

Comment: I want to know something, can I update dart for only one project or it will update automatically to all projects  @julemand101

Comment: @Ahmed You can use a newer version of the Dart distribution in a project which requires a lower version in the pubspec.yaml. Dart will then disable features which should not be available for the version your project requires. So yes, you can just update your Dart distribution to newest version and it should work for all your project even if they are not ready to use newest version of Dart. When you are ready to upgrade, just change the minimum required Dart version in your `pubspec.yaml` file.